# Implementing the Cosine similarity in tensor flow

Tags: tensorflow, cosine-similarity

My Question is for the below equation [image]

The equation above of single vector. But if I have a batches of vectors,  like my X and Y  having the dimension of (None, 32), then there will some issue.

Also remember in coding environment, one example inside  the batch is already in transpose shape. My problem is when we need to do transpose on [None, 32] the code will not accept and transpose for None dimenation.So I solve it in the following way:

```
def Cosine_similarity(X, Y, feature_dim):

  L = tf.compat.v1.initializers.glorot_normal()(shape=[feature_dim, feature_dim])

  out1 = tf.matmul(X, L)
  out2 = tf.matmul(Y, L)

  out_numerator = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(out1, out2), axis = 1)

  out3 = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(out1, out1), axis = 1)
  out3 = tf.sqrt(out3)

  out4 = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(out2, out2), axis = 1)
  out4 = tf.sqrt(out4)

  out_denominator = tf.multiply(out3, out4)

  final_out = tf.divide(out_numerator, out_denominator)

return final_out
```

And this is coming from the following:

```
<XA.YA> = (XA)^T (YA)

        = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply((X A) , (Y A)), axis = 1)
```

So I just to know if this implementation is right? Or you can correct me if I am missing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand your concern for the (none) dimension.

If I understand correctly the cosine similarity between two identically shaped matrix `X` and `Y` (`[batch, target_dim]`) is just a matrix multiplication of `X * Y^T` with some L2 normalization. Note `X` would be your `out1` and `Y` would be your `out2`.

```py
def Cosine_similarity(x, y, A):
  """Pair-wise Cosine similarity.

  First `x` and `y` are transformed by A.
  `X = xA^T` with shape [batch, target_dim],
  `Y = yA^T` with shape [batch, target_dim].

  Args:
    x: shaped [batch, feature_dim].
    y: shaped [batch, feature_dim].
    A: shaped [targte_dim, feature_dim]. Transformation matrix to project
      from `feature_dim` to `target_dim`.

  Returns:
    A cosine similarity matrix shaped [batch, batch]. The entry
    at (i, j) is the cosine similarity value between vector `X[i, :]` and
    `Y[j, :]` where `X`, `Y` are the transformed `x` and y` by `A` 
    respectively. In the other word, entry at (i, j) is the pair-wise 
    cosine similarity value between the i-th example of `x` and the j-th 
    example of `y`.
  """

  x = tf.matmul(x, A, transpose_b=True)
  y = tf.matmul(y, A, transpose_b=True)
  x_norm = tf.nn.l2_normalize(x, axis=-1)
  y_norm = tf.nn.l2_normalize(y, axis=-1)
  y_norm_trans = tf.transpose(y_norm, [1, 0])
  sim = tf.matmul(x_norm, y_norm_trans)
  return sim

import numpy as np

feature_dim = 8
target_dim = 4
batch_size = 2
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, dim))
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, dim))
A = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(target_dim, feature_dim))

sim = Cosine_similarity(x, y, A)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  x, y, sim = sess.run([x, y, sim], feed_dict={
      x: np.ones((batch_size, feature_dim)), 
      y: np.random.rand(batch_size, feature_dim),
      A: np.random.rand(target_dim, feature_dim)})
  print 'x=\n', x
  print 'y=\n', y
  print 'sim=\n', sim
```

Result:

```
x=
[[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]]
y=
[[ 0.01471654  0.76577073  0.97747731  0.06429122  0.91344446  0.47987637
   0.09899797  0.773938  ]
 [ 0.8555786   0.43403915  0.92445409  0.03393625  0.30154493  0.60895061
   0.1233703   0.58597666]]
sim=
[[ 0.95917791  0.98181278]
 [ 0.95917791  0.98181278]]
```

Comment: you didn't include the transformation matrix A in the equation above.

Comment: I might miss something. I don't really think that matters. I have added the transformation matrix.

Comment: why we don't do tf.reduce_sum( tf.multiply(x_norm, y_norm), axis= 1), instead of taking transpose of y and do matmul. Is this because in your case you are taking the similarity between all the four examples ( two from each batch), like one example from X and the remaining  two examples in Y that's why your similarity matrix output have 4 values. While in my case I will do element-wise similarity between the X and Y batches in which  in my case it will be two scaler values. Am I right?

Comment: I have a few typos and now they are fixed. My intuition is that when both `x` and `y` are matrices, it makes sense to compute the pair-wise similarity matrix between every example in `x` and every example in `y`. That's why the output matrix is shaped `[batch, batch]`. Also this is actually consistent with sklearn's pair-wise cosine similarity define here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html.   In your code, you have only two values because you never have interactions between x[1, :] and y[0, :] or between x[0, :] and y[1, :].

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solve my problem now, and actually it is kind of give me an idea to solve another issue I have it with Distance metric. I will try to post about it soon and refer to you. The elemnt-wise way that I did  before because in my siamese network the input is in  way that there is no  full interaction between all examples in X and Y. But Actually I can modified it and make that interaction and get the similarity label between them. It  will make the metric even better but I think the training will be slower. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad this helps.

Comment: What about full_pairs , I mean if we have batch_size of 20 examples, and the similarity matrix will be ( 20 X 20). I did it  in the code, but it is very slow as I am considering each example in the batch with  all other examples in the batch? Do you thing that pair-wise similarity better  than taking full pairs?

Comment: I am confused about your comparison between `full_pairs` and `pair-wise`. They look identical to me. What do you mean?

Comment: Sorry I did mistake when I said the similarity matrix will be 20X 20. It will be 20 X 39. I mean if we have 20 examples against 20 examples, then I will take the one example from the first batch against all examples in the second batch plus against all examples in the first batch except the example itself. Is this will be better?

Comment: You might want to open another question. I cannot figure out what is the relation between your first batch/second batch with your problem here (`x`, `y`).